# Beta testing issue in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, itunes, testflight, applepay, beta-testing

When build uploading to testflight its working fine. Facing issue when app sharing to users by beta testing. Please check the issue in the bellow attachment.

[image]

Comment: the error message is quite straight forward.

Comment: But i added privacy policy in iTunes app information.

Comment: You should add a entitlements file into the project.

Comment: Thank you guys for giving reply to me. I got the solution from below link  (https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/43085100/external+tester+submission+error+beta+app+review+entitlements+for+apple+pay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution last comment from below attached link. I hope it helpful to you friends.

https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/43085100/external+tester+submission+error+beta+app+review+entitlements+for+apple+pay